# Get all shared folders an Active Directory user has access to

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am looking to find all of the folders that an Active Directory user has access to.

All I can find is Active Directory users in a folder, but this is not what I am trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you referring to all the LOCAL folders the user has access to, or ALL folders (including LAN file servers)?  (I doubt there is a way to get folders from anything outside the LAN).

Comment: If the users have thousands of accessible directories in the Local, you want to show it all too? Or there is another qualification for the directories to be shown?

Comment: In active directory, there are shared folders. like in this image: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb742437.managa16_big%28l=en-us%29.gif
The shared folder is called "Engineering Specs". I am look up all folders that a user is a member of. So lookup folders by username. Is this possible?

Comment: Also, I am looking to make a C# application do the search, so it will always be a computer on the LAN, and on the Domain.

Comment: Those permissions aren't stored inside AD - you'd have to scan all relevant disks/drives and examine the permissions on every single share of every single drive........